defineModel with defineComponentBinds
I'm trying to use vee-validate's defineComponentBinds with defineModel in a child component.
My code is something like this:
const companyCity = defineComponentBinds('companyCity', ValidationMode.eager);

<AddressFields
   v-model:city="companyCity.modelValue"
/>

And my AddressFields component:
const city = defineModel<string | undefined>('city',{ required: true });

      <ui-input v-model="city" />

I only added the relevant bits of the code.
As far as I understand, the defineModel macro should create a prop that will be updated in the parent, but for me it doesn't update anything.
I'm thinking that v-model:city="companyCity.modelValue" shouldn't actually have modelValue and I should pass a ref, but TS complains if I only put companyCity in there.
